# Why are eclipse views sometimes empty?

Tags: eclipse

I have to use eclipse 3.1. I'm using it in an Ubuntu 11.04 VM (VMWare). It seems that every view I use is initially blank/empty until I close and reopen it. This is annoying but I can deal with it.

The problem is this trick doesn't work with the view for source code files.

Has anyone ever seen a similar issue? Are there any work-arounds?

I don't know if it is related. But the main menu is also initially missing. If I resize the application window, the main menu reappears.

Comment: Can you use a more up-to-date version of eclipse? (3.6 is the current version, 3.1 was released in 2005)

Comment: I'm not sure. I'm trying to use an old version of Wind River Workbench (version 2.4). I think, but I'm not sure, that they bundle their plugin with a specific version of eclipse.

Comment: Are you talking about standard eclipse views, or those provided (or customized by) by Workbench?

Comment: It was pretty much every view. Some standard and some workbench-specific. @Rob Woolley's answer below worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue with newer Linux desktops when using older versions of Eclipse.

The GTK widget set changed the default way it renders widgets.  This causes versions of Eclipse that were compiled against the old GTK library to experience empty views like you saw as well as problems with ignoring some mouse clicks on buttons.

If you set this environment variable before launching Workbench then it should resolve the problem:
export GDK_NATIVE_WINDOWS=1

I verified this on Ubuntu 11.04 with Workbench 2.6 and the problem went away after I set the variable.

Best regards,
Rob